# Storing NSObjects in file

Tags: iphone

I have huge array with NSobjects. While storing to file iPad is getting memory issues.
I want to store each object in file one by one and again read it back. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend Core Data.  It handles all the heavy lifting in regards to memory.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/CoreData.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively if Core Data feels a little heavy you could implement the NSCoding protocol.

Apple provide a code example [here](http://file:///Library/Developer/Documentation/DocSets/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiOS4_3.iOSLibrary.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/samplecode/CopyPasteTile/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009040)